# How to pass global options to perforce command (P4 api .net)

Tags: c#, .net, api, perforce, p4.net

I was wondering if it is possible to pass global options to perforce commands.

As it stands now, it looks like I'm only able to pass global options to the connection itself

Ex: `connection.UserName = "user"`

Is there a way to pass in global options specific to the command?

ie: `command.UserName = "user"`

Comment: Generally speaking, the global options cannot be varied within a single connection on a command-by-command basis. If you need to run different commands using different usernames, or with different settings for other global options, it is probably best to use multiple connections, one for each specific configuration of global options that you need.